# How to make a layout of an activity visible through programming?

Tags: android, layout, constraints

I have a layout as indicated below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        ...
```

The associated activity is like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_login);// here is the layout
}
```

I'm trying to make it visible in the following way:

```
LinearLayout layoutActLogin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.act_login);
layoutActLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But Android Studio told me that there is an error about R.layout.act_login

Comment: You're mis-understanding how layouts and views work. Layouts define what is shown on-screen to a user during an activity, set by calling `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. Views are individual elements *within* the layout, which are accessed with the `R.id` prefix using `findViewById()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findViewById` is for views, not layouts.

You should put an ID in your view like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        ...
```

Then get the view reference and make it visible

```
View viewActLogin = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
viewActLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks.

ConstraintLayout layoutActLogin = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.act_login_layout);
            layoutActLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 0):

You can not change visibility of `Layout`. you can only change visibility of Views inside.

You can assign `id` to you view by using `android:id` tag in you layout. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#attributes).

In your case. Just give some Id to your `View/ViewGroup`, and reference that `View` from your Activity and using `findViewById` method and change its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how layouts and views work. Layouts define what is shown on-screen to a user during an activity, set by calling `setContentView()` within the Activity's `onCreate()` method. Views are individual elements within the layout, which are accessed with the `R.id` prefix using `findViewById()`.

In your example you'll need to apply an ID to the root `ConstraintLayout` (using `android:id`) to be able to access it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible">
```

Then you can access it with:

```
ConstraintLayout layoutActLogin = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
layoutActLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**EDIT** Looking at your code I now realise you want to control the root `ConstraintLayout`, which makes my answer almost identical to Eduardo Herzer's. Leaving my answer up due to the added explanation at the beginning.